# Compiz Put Stopped Working After Upgrade

Tags: unity, compiz, 14.04, window-management

After upgrading my computer from 13.10 to 14.04, the Put plugin under Compiz has stopped working.  When I press `<Super>` and an arrow on my number pad, it recognizes is as though I'm trying to launch an application with `<Super>+[0-9]` from the launcher.  I've tried with number lock on an off, but it doesn't make a difference.  What might have changed that's causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the actual solution, I found a way around it was to add `<Control>` to the key-bindings, to avoid the binding conflict with the launcher.  It'd still be nice to know how to fix this, through.